# Access folder/file names from remote system

Tags: gwt

I have some folder/files in some remote location and want to read those file/folder names using url from GWT client. I don't want to get those details from server part. 
Can anybody tell me is there any way to read those details.

Thanks..

Comment: What kind of details?

Answer (score 0):

> In my program i have some versions (Ex: 1.0) of help files. And i am
>   maintaining latest version help files in the remote server in folders.
>   Those folder names indicates the help files versions. Whenever i open
>   my JWT<sub>(sic)</sub>  application in browser i want to check for
>   availability of latest versions and notify to user.

The browser can't know what "files" a server has unless the server explicit tells them so. There isn't much that GWT can do or any other Javascript framework, in my experience, about this particular problem. I see you have two options

1. Code a server endpoint where you query if the help files changed and their location
2. Drop this requirement, users don't need to know when the help file changes, if they need help, they look for those. Put the files in a `/latest/` location. If you really need the version, add to the help file footer. This way the user can tell if there was any change.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: In my program i have some versions (Ex: 1.0) of help files.  And i am maintaining latest version help files in the remote server in folders. Those folder names indicates the help files versions.  Whenever i open my JWT application in browser i want to check for availability of latest versions and notify to user.